# Type 'Listing | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Listing'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Listing'

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi seeking help in my project
The thing is, I am struggling with an error
https://github.com/abhijitutkarsh/buyandsell/blob/main/src/app/listing-detail-page/listing-detail-page.component.ts
above link has the code base when compiling it is showing an error saying

```
src/app/listing-detail-page/listing-detail-page.component.ts:20:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Listing | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Listing'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Listing'.

20 this.listing = fakeListings.find(listing => listing.id === id);
```

Basically the code about showing data from the fake-data.ts. here i am getting the id from the router url. just stuck here. The issue is kind of minor, not able to identify

Comment: `.find()` may  return `undefined`

Comment: Yes, I am trying to declare the listing:Listing such that it will be defined and will not give error in the this.listing in ngoninit().......when we use listing:Listing[] =[]; this doesn't give error...when we dont use braces it gives error why is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for find to return undefined when it did not find a result.
You can add undefined to the listing type:

```
  listing: Listing | undefined;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.listing = fakeListings.find(listing => listing.id === id);
  }
```

Or check if there is a result:

```
  listing: Listing;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const fakeListing = fakeListings.find(listing => listing.id === id);

    if (fakeListing !== undefined){
      this.listing = fakeListing;
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey thanks it works....the second one

Comment: In your case, the second option is a better solution. In the else can also return to the previous page when it is undefined. When the result is undefined you have no data to show so the page has no use and the overview might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

this.listing = fakeListings.find(l => l.id === id) as Listing;